# profile projection of an image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, orientation, projection

It is said to divide the image into non-overlapping blocks and then the projection profile of the valleys and ridges along a line perpendicular to the local ridge orientation in each block should be calculated.

I have already divided the image into blocks and the ridge orientation is estimated. Is it correct to use `Pp=improfile(im)` to measure the projection profile?

How to make it perpendicular to ridge orientation then?